# Is there a way to use CSS to force (print mode) to fit into 1 page?

Tags: html, css, printing, pdf-generation

I have a report HTML that if I hit print, it needs more than a page

[image]

My goal is not to reduce my HTML since it's already nice as is.

---

## Note

I found a way to use Scale to 85% in Chrome, and that will fit nicely in1 the page.

[image]

but ... I'm still curious if there are other ways out there to achieve it

---

Is there a way to use CSS to force it (print mode) to fit into 1 page?

Comment: Not tested but as ideas: `scale()` on `body` could do the trick maybe very easily ... but it scales horizontal and vertical at the same time. Another rough approach: if you use `em` and relative sizes as perecentage for sizing all elements it should be possible to scale it by changing the base for the sizes just in the `body` and jus to differ the width by some printing classes. Most elegant could be to use a complex separate printing stylesheet so you are able to doe sizing in `mm` or `cm` which could be usefull for a perfect positioning of the elements on a sheet of paper.